# ContentView as Resource Dictionary

Tags: xamarin.forms

Reusable layout can be have in a `ContentView` in a seperate file and use like this:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <local:MyContentView/>
 </StackLayout>
```

However, is it possible if I want to have the ContentView as a resource dictionary in the same file and use it?. Something like this is what I'm after:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ContentView x:Key="MyContentView">
            <!--Some Views-->
        </ContentView>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then how would I use this `key` in my StackLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the ControlTemplate in the ResourceDictionary and use it in the Xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyContentView">

            <Label Text="tttttt" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            
        </ControlTemplate>


    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->

    <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyContentView}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

</StackLayout>
```